# IOptions with Connection string

Tags: c#, .net, connection-string

I have very simple appsettings:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=test;Database=test;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Class for connection string:

```
public class ConnectionStrings
    {
      public string DefaultConnection { get; set; }
    }
```

I register in DI it like this:

```
builder.Services.AddOptions<ConnectionStrings>(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
```

I inject IOption in constructor, but it is always null:

```
public class ShoppingCartRepository : IShoppingCartRepository
  {
    private readonly IOptions<ConnectionStrings> _connectionStrings;

    public ShoppingCartRepository(IOptions<ConnectionStrings> connectionStrings)
    {
      _connectionStrings = connectionStrings;
    }

    // ...
 
    }
  }
```

Can I use IOptions for connection string or I should use another approach?

What is best way of working with connection string?

Comment: Which version of `.net core` you used?

Comment: I use in my project net6.0

Comment: If your application used EF Core you should use `AddDbContext` instead of manually connecting to the database, especially in web applications. DbContext is scoped to the request as it should, thus giving automatic Unit-of-Work and rollback semantics - if you want to reject changes, just don't call `SaveChanges` and they'll disappear when DbContext is disposed at the end of the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AddOptions` method accept an argument of type `string` that is the name of the options instance. But You pass the value of `DefaultConnection` in `appsettings.json` to it.

You should add `Bind` method after `AddOptions`

```cs
builder.Services
    .AddOptions<ConnectionStrings>()
    .Bind(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"));
```

Comment: We cannot pass string to Bind method, but we can pass IConfigurationSection:      `builder.Services.AddOptions<ConnectionStrings>()
        .Bind(builder.Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));`

Answer (score 0):

Let's take it from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#appsettingsjson):

```
builder.Services.Configure<ConnectionStrings>(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")
)
```

Comment: I tried this way and it works, but I want to use AddOptions with GetConnectionString method. I don't understand why I can't use them, they look much better for this purpose